# How to ignore the sign of a variable in C?

Tags: c

I am using C as the programming language.
How to ignore the sign when using float/signed int  variables?
For example if float/signed int  f = -40 or +40
The result should be same after a mathematical operation like a+b*f

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `abs` for ints or `fabs` for floats.

```
a+b*abs(f)
```

**EDIT:** It's not clear wether you want -40 to be treated as 40 or vice versa, if you for some reason wan't the latter:

```
a+b*-abs(f)
```

Comment: Don't forget `labs` for longs!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for absolute value?

`#include<math.h>` includes `abs` for integers, `fabs` for floats.

Answer (score 0):

`abs` or `fabs`?

Answer (score 0):

use the function `abs()` to return the absolute value

Answer (score 0):

`fabsf(f)` returns the absolute value of `f`: `fabsf(40) == 40` and also `fabsf(-40) == 40`.